# how to send text to server from client websocket qt

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qtwebsockets

I tried to modify the code from the qt documentation, to process strings entered from the keyboard, and if it is not a command (starting with '-'), then send it to the server:
`echoclient.cpp :`

```
//! [constructor]
EchoClient::EchoClient(const QUrl &url, bool debug, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_debug(debug)
{
    if (m_debug)
        qDebug() << "WebSocket server:" << url;
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::connected, this, &EchoClient::onConnected);
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::disconnected, this, &EchoClient::closed);
    m_webSocket.open(url);
}
//! [constructor]

//! [onConnected]
void EchoClient::onConnected()
{
    if (m_debug)
        qDebug() << "WebSocket connected";
    m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(QStringLiteral("Hello, world!"));
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,
            this, &EchoClient::onTextMessageReceived);

    
}
//! [onConnected]

//! [onTextMessageReceived]
void EchoClient::onTextMessageReceived(QString message)
{
    if (m_debug)
        qDebug() << "Message received:" << message;
    //m_webSocket.close();
}
//! [onTextMessageReceived]

void EchoClient::Run() {
    CommandProcessing();
}

void EchoClient::CommandProcessing() {
    QTextStream qtin(stdin);
    while(true) {
        QString text;
        text = qtin.readLine();
        if (text[0] == '-') {
            // if text is command
        }
        else {
            // Send msg
            m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(text);
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace Qt::Literals::StringLiterals;
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QUrl url("ws://localhost:1234");
    qDebug() << url;

    EchoClient client(url, true);

    QObject::connect(&client, &EchoClient::closed, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);

    client.Run();


    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to process strings after establishing a connection between the client and the server, but when using the `Run()` method, the client cannot even connect to the server; without `Run()` everything works. I also tried to use the `isValid()` method of `m_webSocket` to see if I could work with it, but it also did not give results. I commented out `m_webSocket.close()` to continue working with websockets

Comment: Have you forgotten to connect the the slot onTextMessageReceived when you have a connection from server? It should be connected to the signal Websocket::textMessageReceived(const QString &message)

Comment: @sav in method `onConnected` i connect it